# Does the word "luminaria" mean "anything that glows"?

Tags: meaning

I came back from one benefit concert, and they announced there "Please stop by at our booth and buy glow rings, glow sticks, flash lights, and other luminaria" (it was dark). I immediately understood what they meant by "luminaria". They had a large display with all things glowing and flashing, like flashing earrings, trinkets, LED bracelets ...

However, now at home I see that none of the dictionaries agree with this meaning. Both Wiktionary and Merriam-Webster say that it is a *lantern* or *vigil fire* from Hispanic culture.

Google image search fetches a collection pictures of vigil lanterns, and not much else.

I feel it isn't correct to say *other luminaria*, because *other* implies that *luminaria* is a collective name for all sorts of glowing things, when it is defined as a much more specific thing.

So did they use the word *luminaria* correctly, and most people, like me, understood them, and dictionaries are missing this meaning, or this isn't the correct use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an 'improper' use of the original [Spanish](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/es/definicion/espanol/luminaria) term where it is used in a more general sense and refers to lights used especially during festivities:

[Luminaria](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/luminaria) ‎(plural luminarias):

> - a vigil fire used in ceremonies in Native American and Hispanic cultures
> - a makeshift lantern used as a holiday decoration, especially in Hispanic culture.

Etymology:

> - From Late Latin luminaria, neuter plural of luminare, from Latin lumen.

From [The Complete Idiot's Guide to Crafts With Kids](https://books.google.it/books?id=ewCIMr_FqpoC&pg=PA269&dq=%22luminaria%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CFMQ6AEwB2oVChMI9r7jpYrxxwIVwTcUCh0cUw8w#v=onepage&q=%22luminaria%22&f=false):

> - For light ing the way for their friends and neighbors, ***children can make luminaria,*** light sources that shine through paper bags. If you live near a party store, drop by and pick up coated, colored paper bags. If you can't find colored bags, plain ...

Comment: It is insufficiently established to be in the OED. It seems like a convenient *ad hoc* coinage from the Romance languages - and may be found in different senses.

Comment: In Latin _luminarium_ means _light_, _lamp_, and Latin plural _luminaria_ would match what they meant (_lights_).